# How to get the coordinates of a user drawn line in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I understand that you can draw lines using the canvas element. What I want to accomplish, is the user selects 2 points on the canvas. Then, using the 2 points I can calculate the equation of this line. However, I have not been able to figure out how I can access the coordinates property of the dots that a user draws on the canvas. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If the user needs to click to select the points, you want to look into [addEventListnener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and the [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) object that is passed into the event handler that you register.

For example:

```
canvasElement.addEventListener("click", function(event /* MouseEvent */) {
  // now event.clientX and event.clientY have mouse coordinates
});
```

Comment: How can I get the coordinates of the point the user clicked after they do so?

Comment: Just as I said.